# rxjs observable reusing logic

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm writing a angular file-upload component.

Upon successful upload, it displays a notice and two buttons:

- `replace` : deletes uploaded file and opens the file-selector dialog
- `remove` : deletes uploaded file and displays a notice

Deleting the uploaded file means making a HTTP DELETE request to a backend system and handling possible failure and retries.

```
_handleReplace() {
  this.replaceClicked$.pipe(
    tap((x) => this._backend.delete(this.file, this.fieldName)),
    tap((x) => openFileSelectorDialog())
  );
}

_handleRemove() {
  this.replaceClicked$.pipe(
    tap((x) => this._backend.delete(this.file, this.fieldName)),
    tap((x) => displayNotice())
  );
}
```

In this snippet I'm not dealing with possible failure and retries.

How can I extract the deletion logic to avoid repeating it in two methods?

Or more generically, how can I apply common transformations on two different observables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the pipe method to create a custom operator like this:

```
deleteFile = () => pipe(
    tap((x) => this._backend.delete(this.file, this.fieldName))
  );    

_handleReplace() {
  this.replaceClicked$.pipe(
    deleteFile(),
    tap((x) => openFileSelectorDialog())
  );
}

_handleRemove() {
  this.replaceClicked$.pipe(
    deleteFile(),
    tap((x) => displayNotice())
  );
}
```

The pipe function should be imported from rxjs:

```
import { pipe } from "rxjs";
```

Comment: Thanks, from your example I did some more research and I found this post that provides more context https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44