# How to pass parameters to wrapped '.pipe()' logic from inside of another .pipe()

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9

I have to execute the same logic for different service calls (e.g.: `myService.getA()` and `myService.putA()`). The logic includes other service calls, thus i make those calls from within the `.pipe()`.

My current logic is as follow:

```
this.myService.getItemA()
    .pipe(
        filter(itemA => {
            if (itemA.property) {
                this.itemA = itemA;
                return true;
            } else {
                this.someLogic(itemA);
                return false;
            }
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.anotherService.getItemB()),
        tap(itemB => {
            this.anotherLogic(itemB);
            this.someLogic(this.itemA);
        })
    ).subscribe();
```

```
this.myService.putItemA()
    .pipe(
        filter(itemA => {
            if (itemA.property) {
              this.itemA = itemA;
              return true;
            } else {
              this.someLogic(iteamA);
              return false;
            }
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.anotherService.getItemB()),
        tap(itemB =>{
            this.anotherLogic(itemB);
            this.someLogic(this.itemA);
        })
    ).subscribe();
```

What i found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907458/rxjs-observable-reusing-logic) is that it can be done just by wrapping the shared logic in a function variable:

```
private prepareData= (itemA: IteamA) => pipe(
    filter(() => {
      if (itemA.property) {
        this.itemA = itemA;
        return true;
      } else {
        this.someLogic(iteamA);
        return false;
      }
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.anotherService.getItemB()),
    tap(itemB => {
        this.anotherLogic(itemB);
        this.someLogic(this.itemA);
    })
  );
```

and then use it like this:

```
this.myService.putItemA()
    .pipe(
        tap(itemA=> this.temporaryIteamA = this.itemA)
        this.prepareData(this.temporaryItemA)
    ).subscribe();
```

but, considering that my `putItemA()` already returns an `Observable<ItemA>` i would like to just write like the following:

```
this.myService.putItemA()
    .pipe(
        this.prepareData(itemA)
    ).subscribe();
```

and

```
this.myService.getItemA()
    .pipe(
        this.prepareData(itemA)
    ).subscribe();
```

How should i modify the `prepareData()` to implicity receive the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are working with Observable pipes, as the name suggest it, all the emmited values are **piped** into the defined pipe (see it as a real pipe) so you can do whatever operations, modify the value, change the emitting source, and many more complex scenarios.

That said, when you create a custom pipe (or operator) you can either directly define it as a pipe...

```
const myPipe = pipe(
    switchMap(emmitedValue => of(`${emmitedValue} How are you?`))
);
```

or you can define it as a function which returns a pipe...

```
const myPipe2 = optionalMessage => pipe(
  switchMap((emmitedValue) => of(`${emmitedValue} How are you? ${optionalMessage}`))
);
```

Then you can use those pipes, the first one by passing its reference (you will still receive the emmited values there) and the second one by calling that function which return the desired pipe (hence you can pass more parameters than just the emmited value).

```
of('Biiz').pipe(
  map(x => `Hello ${x}!`),
  myPipe,
).subscribe(console.log);

of('Biiz').pipe(
  map(x => `Hello ${x}!`),
  myPipe2(`It's a sunny day `),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

(You can check that example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xukend))

For your case, you should define your custom operator by just receiving the emmited value in the pipe:

```
private prepareData = pipe(
    filter((itemA: IteamA) => {
      if (itemA.property) {
        this.itemA = itemA;
        return true;
      } else {
        this.someLogic(iteamA);
        return false;
      }
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.anotherService.getItemB()),
    tap(itemB => {
        this.anotherLogic(itemB);
        this.someLogic(this.itemA);
    })
  );
```

And use it by passing it's reference:

```
  this.myService.putItemA()
      .pipe(
          this.prepareData
      ).subscribe();
  
  // or
  
  this.myService.getItemA()
      .pipe(
          this.prepareData
      ).subscribe();
```

Comment: of course the value, being inside a pipe(), is already piped. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to have a wrapper in your case.

Just try the following:

```
import { pipe } from 'rxjs'

const prepareData = pipe(
  filter(itemA => {
    if (itemA.property) {
      this.itemA = itemA;
      return true;
    } else {
      this.someLogic(itemA);
      return false;
    }
  }),
  switchMap(() => this.anotherService.getItemB()),
  tap(itemB => {
    this.anotherLogic(itemB);
    this.someLogic(this.itemA);
  })
);
```

and then

```
this.myService.getItemA().pipe(prepareData).subscribe(...)

this.myService.putItemA().pipe(prepareData).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer, that is correct, but the @Sebastiandg7 is more descriptive and cover more cases